# Invalid method Custom_Abc_Model_Custom::addFieldToFilter admin Panel of Magento CE 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, php, ce-1.9.0.1, collection, filter

Hello In my grid file while filtering collection but it is showing error.

Here is the code of my grid file

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {

    $custom_id = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getCustom()->getId();

    $collection = Mage::getModel('custom_abc/custom')
            ->addFieldToFilter('custom_id',1)
            ->getCollection();

    $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
    $store = $this->_getStore();

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Here is my model

**Model/Custom.php**

```
class Custom_ABC_Model_Custom extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
  public function _construct()
  {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('custom_abc/custom');
  }
}
```

**Model/Resource/Custom.php**

```
class Custom_ABC_Model_Resource_Custom extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract 
{
  public function _construct()
   {
       $this->_init('custom_abc/custom', 'custom_id');
   }
}
```

**Model/Resource/Custom/Collection.php**

```
class Custom_ABC_Model_Resource_Custom_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{

  protected function _construct()
  {
      parent::_construct();
      $this->_init('custom_abc/custom');
  }

}
```

Comment: where is the class Invalid `Custom_Abc_Model_Customize`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can only apply the `addFieldToFilter` once you've got the collection, so instead of this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('custom_abc/custom')
            ->addFieldToFilter('custom_id',1)
            ->getCollection();
```

You should do:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('custom_abc/custom')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('custom_id',1);
```

Also a lighter syntax could be:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('custom_abc/custom_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('custom_id',1);
```